# BaseUri in Saxon causing problems when trying to compile xslt content

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, uri, saxon

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/data.xml");
    string xslt = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/dataXslt.xsl");
    string xmlCopy = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/data.xml");

    TransformData(xml, xmlCopy, xslt);
}

static public void TransformData(string data, string xmlCopy, string xslt)
{
    // Create a Processor instance.
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    // Create a compiled stylesheet
    processor.NewXsltCompiler().BaseUri = new Uri("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon");
    XsltExecutable templates = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xslt)));

    // Note: we could actually use the same Xslt30Transformer in this case.
    // But in principle, the two transformations could be done in parallel in separate threads.

    // Do the first transformation
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----- transform of " + data + " -----");
    Xslt30Transformer transformer1 = templates.Load30();
    XdmNode input1 = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(data)));
    transformer1.ApplyTemplates(input1, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));     // default destination is Console.Out

    // Do the second transformation
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----- transform of " + xmlCopy + " -----");
    Xslt30Transformer transformer2 = templates.Load30();
    XdmNode input2 = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlCopy)));
    transformer2.ApplyTemplates(input2, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));     // default destination is Console.Out
}
```

Here's the error I keep getting no matter if I remove the BaseUri or not.

*Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: BaseUri
   at Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler.Compile(XmlReader reader)
   at Saxon.Program.TransformData(String data, String xmlCopy, String xslt) in C:\Users\Davíð\source\Saxon\Saxon\Program.cs:line 33
   at Saxon.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Davíð\source\Saxon\Saxon\Program.cs:line 22*

---

Based on comments, fixed & working code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{
    string xml = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/data.xml");
    string xslt = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/dataXslt.xsl");

    TransformData(xml, xml, xslt);
}

static public void TransformData(string data, string xmlCopy, string xslt)
{
    // Create a Processor instance.
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    // Create a compiled stylesheet
    var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
    compiler.BaseUri = new Uri("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon");
    XsltExecutable templates = compiler.Compile(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslt)));

    // Note: we could actually use the same Xslt30Transformer in this case.
    // But in principle, the two transformations could be done in parallel in separate threads.

    // Do the first transformation
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----- transform of " + data + " -----");
    Xslt30Transformer transformer1 = templates.Load30();
    XdmNode input1 = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(data)));
    transformer1.ApplyTemplates(input1, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));     // default destination is Console.Out

    // Do the second transformation
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----- transform of " + xmlCopy + " -----");
    Xslt30Transformer transformer2 = templates.Load30();
    XdmNode input2 = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlCopy)));
    transformer2.ApplyTemplates(input2, processor.NewSerializer(Console.Out));     // default destination is Console.Out
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide the exact edition and version of Saxon you are using? A stack trace would also help. Do you actually need to parse the XML as a .NET string, as your code does? Simply building with the document builder from a file/URI should be easier and better deal with different encodings than using ReadAllText.

Comment: No idea whether this causes your problem, but [`XmlTextReader` has been deprecated since .Net 2.0 over 10 years ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?view=netframework-4.8).  Instead, use [`XmlReader.Create(TextReader)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlReader_Create_System_IO_TextReader_).  Also, be sure to dispose of it afterwards.

Comment: Also, might you please [edit] your question to include the following: 1) the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any.  2) A [mcve] showing minimal sample XML and XSL files that reproduce the problem?  We're much more likely to be able to solve your problem if we can reproduce your problem.  See: [ask], the [tour], and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: [`processor.NewXsltCompiler()`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Processor.html#NewXsltCompiler()) returns a new `XsltCompiler` each time it is called.  You call it **twice**: you set `BaseUri` on the first, then create another to do you processing.  Have you tried `var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler(); compiler.BaseUri = new Uri("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon"); var templates = compiler.Compile( /* Remainder as before ... `?

Comment: By the way, strings in .Net are immutable, so there is never a reason to deep-clone a string by reading a file **twice**, as you are doing with `xmlCopy`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! They helped a lot, and enabled me to make this work.
I will edit my question with the working sample.

Comment: @DavidBirgis - you seem to have answered your question in your question by incorporating my comments.  Should I make an actual answer, which you could [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)?

Comment: @dbc Yes, you can do that. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidBirgis - done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues:

- [`processor.NewXsltCompiler()`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Processor.html#NewXsltCompiler()) returns a new `XsltCompiler` each time it is called.  You call it **twice**:

  ```
  processor.NewXsltCompiler().BaseUri = new Uri("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon");
  XsltExecutable templates = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xslt)));
  ```

  The code sets [`BaseUri`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltCompiler.html#BaseUri) on the first, then create another to do the compiling.  As such `BaseUri` is never set on the `XsltCompiler` that is actually used to do work.

  This is the immediate cause of the exception *Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: BaseUri at Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler.Compile(XmlReader reader)*.

  You should instead create just one `XsltCompiler`.
- You are using `XmlTextReader`, but [`XmlTextReader` has been deprecated since .Net 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?view=netframework-4.8) over 10 years ago. Instead, use [`XmlReader.Create(TextReader)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlReader_Create_System_IO_TextReader_). Also, be sure to dispose of it afterwards.
- You load the two copies of the contents of the file `data.xml` into memory, into the strings `xml` and  `xmlCopy`.  But strings in .Net are immutable so there is no need to do this.

Thus your code should look something like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/data.xml");
    string xslt = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon/dataXslt.xsl");

    TransformData(xml, xml, xslt);
}

static public void TransformData(string xml1, string xml2, string xslt)
{
    // Create a Processor instance.
    var processor = new Processor();

    // Create a compiled stylesheet
    var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
    compiler.BaseUri = new Uri("C:/Users/Davíð/source/Saxon/Saxon");
    XsltExecutable templates;
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslt)))
        templates = compiler.Compile(reader);

    // Note: we could actually use the same Xslt30Transformer in this case.
    // But in principle, the two transformations could be done in parallel in separate threads.

    // Do the first transformation
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----- transform of " + xml1 + " -----");
    TransformData(processor, templates, xml1, Console.Out);

    // Do the second transformation
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----- transform of " + xml2 + " -----");
    TransformData(processor, templates, xml2, Console.Out);
}

private static void TransformData(Processor processor, XsltExecutable templates, string xml, TextWriter output)
{
    var transformer = templates.Load30();
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
    {
        var input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(reader);
        transformer.ApplyTemplates(input, processor.NewSerializer(output));
    }
}
```